# How do I return all individuals that have one characteristic in one row, and a different characteristic in another?

Tags: r

I have a data frame filled with individuals (fish) that were caught using different methods. I want to get a list of all fish that were caught using more than one method.

My data frame looks something like this:

| TagNumber | MethodCaught |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | B |
| 2 | A |
| 3 | A |
| 3 | A |

So I want a few lines of code that would tell me tag number 1 & 2 were caught using more than one method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dplyr`'s `distinct` (to remove duplicates), `count` (to tally the number of methods), and `filter` (to remove those with only one method):

```
df %>%
  distinct(TagNumber, MethodCaught) %>%
  count(TagNumber, name = "n_methods") %>%
  filter(n_methods > 1)

#   TagNumber n_methods
# 1         1         2
# 2         2         2
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer by @jpsmith is great, so here just offering an alternative solution:

```
TagNumber <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)
MethodCaught <- c('A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'A')

df <- data.frame(TagNumber, MethodCaught)

df %>% group_by(TagNumber, MethodCaught) %>%
  summarise_all(.funs = sum,na.rm=T)
```

Lists and groups each `TagNumber` and each `MethodCaught` per.